# Clojure timbre 4.0 set-config

Tags: clojure, timbre

I'm using timbre to do logging in clojure.  I like the package, but when I tried to redirect the logging output to a file, the examples at timbre's github page (and others I found on the web) didn't work.

I got an error telling me **set-config!** had the wrong arity.

I can see from the changelog entries that V4.0.0 release of timbre changed set-config! from 2 args to 1, but I can't find an example of how to use the new interface.  What I want to do is just specify output should go to a "spit file" rather than console.

Comment: there is an example config in sourcecode: https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/blob/master/src/taoensso/timbre.cljx line 57. and it is used like `(set-config! example-config)`

Comment: It is not clear from that example how to log to an output file.

Comment: Answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588781/timbre-set-config-has-changed-arity-thus-dont-know-how-to-use-it-to-output-s/36589126#36589126). Unfortunately I asked the same question.