# timbre `set-config!` has changed arity thus don't know how to use it to output std err/out to a file

Tags: clojure, timbre

I am trying to use https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre to log to a file rather than the console. Here is some documentation I've found on how to do that:

```
; The default setup is simple console logging.  We with to turn off console logging and
; turn on file logging to our chosen filename.
(timbre/set-config! [:appenders :standard-out   :enabled?] false)
(timbre/set-config! [:appenders :spit           :enabled?] true)
(timbre/set-config! [:shared-appender-config :spit-filename] log-file-name)
(timbre/set-config! [:shared-appender-config :spit-filename] log-file-name)
```

This works for a previous version of sente, but not for version [com.taoensso/timbre "4.3.1"]. (For unrelated reasons I need to use the latest). The issue with the above code is that `set-config!` now takes one argument - a hash-map. And I can't find any documentation that would help me with translating the above 'two params' code to the new 'one param' code.

I know there's a very similar question out [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639153/clojure-timbre-4-0-set-config). This question has actual code in it so is more specific. I raised an issue as well. The code above basically comes straight from [here](https://github.com/cloojure/demo-timbre).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To log to a file rather than the console in timbre v4.0.0 (2015 June 10) you can do the following:

```clj
(ns app.core
  (:require [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]
            [taoensso.timbre.appenders.core :as appenders]))

;; Disable logging to the console in timbre v4.0.0:
(timbre/merge-config! {:appenders {:println {:enabled? false}}})

;; Create a "spit to file" appender in timbre v4.0.0: 
(timbre/merge-config! {:appenders {:spit (appenders/spit-appender {:fname "log.txt"})}})
```

Note that in timbre v4.3.1 the following does not remove nor disable the println (console) appender:

```clj
(timbre/merge-config! {:appenders {:println nil}})
```

The related issue can be found here https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre/issues/163

*Addition:*
As Timbre allows to modify it's config map `timbre/*config*` simply by using
the standard clojure API, you may also use

```clj
(timbre/swap-config! assoc-in [:appenders :spit :enabled?] false)
(timbre/swap-config! assoc-in [:appenders :spit] (appenders/spit-appender {:fname "log.txt"}))
```

Based on this you can additionally define a simple helper:

```clj
(def set-log-config-param! (partial timbre/swap-config! assoc-in))
```

and then be consistent with the timbre v3.4.0 set-config! syntax you
have quoted in your question:

```clj
(set-log-config-param! [:appenders :println :enabled?] false)
(set-log-config-param! [:appenders :spit]   (appenders/spit-appender {:fname "log.txt"}))
```

Imho this eases the config transition between timbre v3 and v4 and makes the path to 
the params more readable then the equivalent

```clj
(timbre/merge-config! {:appenders {:println {:enabled? false}}})
(timbre/merge-config! {:appenders {:spit    (appenders/spit-appender {:fname "log.txt"})}})
```

Comment: That works great thanks. You can even do one call, supplying one map, which I just tested on my code.

Comment: Right, you can do `(timbre/merge-config! {:appenders {:println {:enabled? false}
                                   :spit    (appenders/spit-appender {:fname log-file-name})}})`

Answer (score 1):

I got a quick response from the maintainer:

"Usage of the spit (file) appender is documented in the README at https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre#file-appender"

And here's the code to answer the question:

```
;; (:require [taoensso.timbre.appenders.core :as appenders]) ; Add to ns
(timbre/merge-config!  
    {:appenders {:println nil ; Remove println appender
                 :spit (appenders/spit-appender {:fname log-file-name})}})
```

Unfortunately even with the `:println nil` mapentry the same output will go to two places. So this answer is incorrect.